# My StopWatch error (GetTimestamp)

Tags: c#, stopwatch

i have this code, it will be a stopwatch.

Why cannot be accessed with an instance reference?

ERROR:  Member 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Pocitadlo
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int minutys = 0, test = 0;
    Thread sekund;
    TimeSpan ts;
    Stopwatch stopky = new Stopwatch();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void START_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            sekund = new Thread(Sekund_pocet);
            this.START.Visible = false;
            this.STOP.Visible = true;
            sekund.Start();
    }

    public void Sekund_pocet()
    {
        stopky.Start();
        stopky.Stop();
        ts = stopky.GetTimestamp();
        string time = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        cas.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => cas.Text = Convert.ToString(time)));
    }

    private void STOP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.STOP.Visible = false;
        this.START.Visible = true;
        test = 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: also, write your code in english, not everyone speaks czech

Comment: I concur with @Filip most languages regardless of where they're created are in american-english because that is 1. the defacto global language (english) and 2. funky american spellings have crept in and are in everything, so it's best to stick to convention color vs. colour for example. C# is in english, so your code should be too.

Answer (score 5):

[GetTimestamp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp.aspx) is a static method, hence the error. You should do `ts = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` instead.